# IllegalStateException: Scanner closed and Ending application program flow

Tags: java

Can you help me with my assignment please

Write a program to test the Person class defined below. Your test program should create two instances of the class (each to test a different constructor) and test each of the methods. You are also required to illustrate the error in trying to access private data members from the client class (for clarity temporarily change the private modifier to public and test again). See screenshots below for sample output.

The screen shots are displayed as:

```
p1 name = Not Given Age = 0 Gender = U
p2 name = Jane Doe Age = 0 Gender = F
p1 name = John Doe Age = 25 Gender = M
```

and

```
 PersonTester.jave:20: name has private access in Person
        System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

 PersonTester.jave:20: age has private access in Person
        System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

PersonTester.jave:20: gender has private access in Person
        System.out.println("p2 name = " + p2.name + "Age = " + p2.age + "Gender = " + p2.gender);

3 errors
```

Here is the class given

```
class Person {

    // Data Members 
    private String name; // The name of this person
    private int age; // The age of this person
    private char gender; // The gender of this person

    // Default constructor
    public Person() {
        name = "Not Given";
        age = 0;
        gender = 'U';
    }

    // Constructs a new Person with passed name, age, and gender parameters.
    public Person(String personName, int personAge, char personGender) {
    name = personName;
    age = personAge;
    gender = personGender; 
    } 

    // Returns the age of this person.
    public int getAge( ) {
        return age;
    }

    // Returns the gender of this person.
    public char getGender( ) {
        return gender;
    }

    // Returns the name of this person.
    public String getName( ) {
        return name;
    }

   // Sets the age of this person.
   public void setAge( int personAge ) {
        age = personAge;
   }

   // Sets the gender of this person.
   public void setGender(char personGender) {
       gender = personGender;
   }

   // Sets the name of this person.
   public void setName( String personName ) {
       name = personName;
   }

} // end class
```

And here is what I have done

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person_Tester { 

static char gender;

    public static void main(String [] args){ 

        //Create Array
        Person[] p1 = new Person[2]; 
        Person[] p2 = new Person[1];

      try(Scanner string_input = new Scanner(System.in); 
         Scanner int_input = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 

            Person person1 = new Person(); 

            Person person2 = new Person();

            //Enter Details For Person1

            System.out.println("P1 Name: "); 

            person1.setName(string_input.nextLine()); 

            System.out.println("Age: "); 

            person1.setAge(string_input.nextInt()); 

            System.out.println("Gender: "); 

            gender = string_input.next().charAt(0);

            System.out.println(); 

            //Enter Details For Person2 

            System.out.println("P2 Name: "); 

            person2.setName(string_input.nextLine()); 

            System.out.println("Age: "); 

            person2.setAge(string_input.nextInt()); 

            System.out.println("Gender: "); 

            gender = string_input.next().charAt(0);  

            System.out.println(); 

            string_input.close();
            int_input.close();

        }

      }//end for loop 

    }//end main method

}//end class
```

when I run the code this is what I get

```
Name: 
John Doe
Age: 
22
Gender: 
M

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
F

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
    at Person_Tester.main(Person_Tester.java:26)
Name:
```

I've tried taking out

```
string_input.close();
int_input.close();
```

and I get

```
Name: 
john doe
Age: 
22
Gender: 
m

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
f

Name: 
Age: 
21
Gender: 
f

Name: 
Age: 
23
Gender: 
m

Name: 
Age:
```

it stays running and won't let me enter in a name

Can you help me fix it please, I need to have it finished by 1pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  System.out.println("Age: ");

    person1.setAge(Integer.parseInt(string_input.nextLine()));

    System.out.println("Gender: ");

    gender = string_input.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

Always use nextLine because, when you use Scanner.nextInt() and  then call Scanner.nextLine(), it will return the remaining part of the line from the line where you read the int which basically is an empty string.

Javadoc of nextLine()

Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

Comment: thanks very much and i got it running just 3 times, realized where I'd made the mistake :) you couldn't tell me how to use 2 constructors could you as I can't figure it out the question reads "create two instances of the class (each to test a different constructor) and test each of the methods"

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarise what you have written and hopefully it will give you some pointers

```
resource = CreateResource();
for(...) {
  UseResource();
  resource.Close();
}
```

First you create a resource (`string_input` and `int_input`). Then you enter the loop. In the loop you use the resource, then you close the resource, then you use the resource again, then you close it again.

Once you have closed the resource then you should not use it again (or close it either). I would recommend one of two things:

1. Creating your resources once (outside the loop), using them many times (inside the loop), and then closing them once (outside the loop)
2. Creating, using and closing resources all inside the loop (this is the less optimal choice in my opinion).

Comment: I tried putting it outside the for loop but it still stays running and doesn't allow me to enter data into name, I probably should have mentioned I'm only learning to use java.

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming and debugging. A very important problem that you will need is being able to break down a problem to nail down the exact point where it goes wrong. Does the program exit? Or is it 'stuck' on one line?